# Basic DELETE commands in PostgreSQL detecting value as column name

Tags: postgresql, string-constant

I'm trying to delete a row at PostgreSQL using pgAdmin4.
Here is my command:

```
DELETE FROM commissions_user 
WHERE first_name = "Steven";
```

For some reason, the error states that

```
ERROR:  column "Steven" does not exist
LINE 2: WHERE first_name = "Steven";
                           ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 50
```

It's weird, why is "Steven" detected as a column name, shouldn't the column name be first_name?

Comment: Check this mini course: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes instead

```
DELETE FROM commissions_user 
WHERE first_name = 'Steven';
```

Double quotes can be used table and column, and single quotes can be used for strings.

ex.

```
DELETE FROM "commissions_user"
WHERE "first_name" = 'Steven';
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html
**Double quote:**

> A convention often used is to write key words in upper case and names
> in lower case, e.g.:
>
> `UPDATE my_table SET a = 5;`
>
> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
> **quoted identifier**. **It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes (")**. A delimited identifier
> is always an identifier, never a key word. So "select" could be used
> to refer to a column or table named “select”, whereas an unquoted
> select would be taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a
> parse error when used where a table or column name is expected. The
> example can be written with quoted identifiers like this:
> `UPDATE "my_table" SET "a" = 5;`

---

**Single Quote**:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

> A string constant in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters
> bounded by single quotes ('), for example 'This is a string'. To
> include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two
> adjacent single quotes, e.g., 'Dianne''s horse'. Note that this is not
> the same as a double-quote character (")